# NullPointerException while running from TestRunner, same works when I run individually from feature file

Tags: java, junit, cucumber

**Test Runner:**

```
package com.test;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    monochrome = true,
    strict = true,
    dryRun = false,
    glue={"classpath:com/test/stepDefs/"},
    plugin={
            "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.text",
            "html:target/cucumber/cucumber.html",
            "json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json",
            "junit:target/cucumber/cucumber.xml",
    },
    features={"src/test/resources/Samplefeatures"},
    tags = "@Web")

public class TestRunner { }
```

**Dependencies Used**

```
    <junit>4.12</junit>
    <io.cucumber>4.2.0</io.cucumber>
```

It works when i run separately from feature file (Scenario)

***any help is really appreciated here.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your glue and step def code (structure and way you define in runner file)

It seems like your features should be in this structure

```
/src/test/resources/com/test/
```

because your stepdefs are in

```
src/test/java/com/test/stepDefs/
```

This is my `AcceptanceIT.java` runner file , which seems to work fine

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions
  (
       plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "json:target/AcceptanceTestResults.json"
                
        },
        features = "src/test/resources/com/test/",

         glue = {"com.test.stepdefs"},

         tags = "@post or @get",
          publish = true
)
public class AcceptanceIT {
}
```